# join on ping with a range

Tags: range, apache-pig

I am looking for a way to join and lookup a table based on a the range using Pig.

```
T1 : 
Upperlimit    lowerlimit    grade
200           300           X
301           500           Y

T2:
Name      Value
A          250
B          320

Result expected:
Name               grade
A                  X
B                  Y
```

Thanks in advance for the tips / suggestions.

Comment: I am not able think of any solution :(, as I am using Pig 0.12.0

Comment: did not get any ideas :(, I need some directions :( as join is not has the feature.

Comment: Joining the data by `grade`, then filter the record by `name` should work.

Comment: S.Singh, but we have no way to join the Grade with Name correct, as it will not fetch any data...

Comment: Sorry,My bad I considered your expected result as input.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a use case for `CROSS`:

```
T3 = CROSS T1, T2;
T4 = FILTER T3 BY (T2::lowerlimit >= T1::grade AND)...
```